# How do I mount my Samsung galaxy s4 on ubuntu?

Tags: usb-connection-mode, samsung-galaxy-s-4, mount

I'm running ubuntu 12.04 and have a rooted samsung galaxy s4.  The s4 is still 2 software versions back since I need to unroot to update and just havent had the time or energy to do all of the work to get back to where I'm setup.  I think it is 4.2.something.

So when I plug my S4 into ubuntu via usb I get an error message

"Unable to mount SAMSUNG_Android
Error initializing camera:-60: could not lock the device"

With my rooted kindle I run gMTP and that gets me access so I tried it with the S4 and it says nothing is available to connect.

With my old evo I had no trouble.  Even when it wasn't rooted I had access to the sd card just like any other drive being mounted.  What's the deal with this s4?

I do have usb debugging enabled.

Comment: Galaxy S4 uses MTP so you will need to turn debugging off and it should work with gMTP

Comment: I believe I have debugging on on the kindle and gMTP still works.  I'll have to confirm this later.  I might be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a terminal in ubuntu(ctrl+alt+t) and type this commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, launch Software Updater (previously known as Update Manager) and install the available updates.
Afther you pdate everything restart pc.

if you want to revert back before making any changes:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
```

Next time, I think you should ask this is askubuntu.com since it is more of a linux specific problem then android.

Comment: Thank you but what exactly does this do? Is this just updating gMTP? The reason I ask it here is b/c my ubuntu box has no problem recognizing my old HTC evo.  In fact it just opens like any mounted drive automatically as long as I unlock the home screen.  While access is the first step I'm trying to achieve I ultimately want to be able to skip jumping through hoops and just unlock my S4 plug it in to the USB and be in business.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what rat2000 code will do?  I don't like to enter code without having a basic explanation.  Maybe I should ask this at the ubuntu forums...

Comment: This worked and got me directly to the desired result. I recieved an explanation for what the code does here   http://askubuntu.com/questions/345735/what-does-this-code-do-if-entered-in-a-terminal

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a while back. Make sure `USB Debugging` is disabled in the Developer Options menu.

Comment: @geffchang I have USB Debugging enabled and I'm having no trouble mounting the rooted device or the sd card.  I followed the directions posted above by rat 2000 and never had to disable usb debugging.  It just works now.  Check it out.

Comment: @hortstu Thanks, but I was just editing AbandonedGoat's post.

Answer (score 1):

So far I found issues like if you have your `USB Debugging` enable or connect it through `USB 3.0` then get this error. So either you disable that option or connect through `USB 2.0` would work fine. Or best you can do is what @Rat200 suggested [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/53250/73341) I had exact same problem. Hope the answers the question.

Btw It's more of Linux specific problem not android.

Comment: Worked well. Confirmed it was not a USB cable problem by checking Samsung device appeared after launching `lsusb`, but an USB 3.0 port issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried connecting the phone using the usb mass storage option on the device? I usually do that with my S2 to work.

Comment: Where would I find that option?  I've explored settings pretty extensively and didn't see anything along those lines?

Comment: Have you tried the method here? [link](http://www.device-recovery.com/how-to-connect-android-devices-to-pc-with-usb-mass-storage-mode#note3).

Comment: The method suggested by rat2000 worked for me.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad it did.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I connected via a USB 3.0 port, but USB 2.0 on the same notebook worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Trying a different USB port and restarting the ADB server worked for me.